# Using jQuery in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function divlightbox(val)
{
    if(val)
    {
        val=val.replace( /^\s+/g, "" );
        var count_js=0;
        var big_string='';
        document.getElementById("video_lightbox").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("divlightbox").style.display = "block";
        $("#video_lightbox").css({"height":"430px","top":"10%","width":"480px"});
```

I found out that the error is in the above. My question is **can't I use jQuery and traditional JavaScript at same time?** I have done coding like this numerous times and never ran into a problem like this. I used to use jQuery methods like `.hide()` and `.css()` inside JavaScript functions but this time it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery IS javascript. BTW, what error returns the javascript console/firebug?

Comment: what error are you getting?  have you looked at it in firebug?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded at the time this function is called?

Comment: I am calling this function on click event of a link and jQuery is loaded when I call this function...What might be the problem red-X

Comment: When you say *"my error"*, do you mean you're getting an Error message in the console? Or are you saying that it just isn't doing what you want it to do? You haven't actually described the issue you're having.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Maybe you have to provide more information/code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to do things like hide(); and css() you need jquery objects. you can't do them to dom elements.

so you could do `$('#video_lightbox').html("");`
or

```
$('#video_lightbox').empty();
```

Comment: I recall you can also create a jquery object by passing a dom element. ie $(el)

Answer (score 16):

While the other answers fix the specific problems, I don't think the OP's question (**in bold**) is really answered here, as depending on the specific context, `$` *may possibly not be defined as a jQuery object yet* (having had this problem myself a few times now.)

In which case you would need to do something like:

```
function divlightbox(val) {
    // ...
    // just use jQuery instead of $ one time
    jQuery("#video_lightbox").css({"height":"430px","top":"10%","width":"480px"});
}
```

OR

```
function divlightbox(val) {
    // define the $ as jQuery for multiple uses
    jQuery(function($) {
        // ...
        $("#video_lightbox").css("height":"430px");
        $("#video_lightbox").css("top":"10%");
        $("#video_lightbox").css("width":"480px");
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is JavaScript so YES. Instead `.innerHTML=""` just use `.empty()`. Instead `.getElementById()` use `$('#..')` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide error in javascript console.

1) Do you pass a val argument to divlightbox function()? When do you call it?

2) why do you use the same identifier `divlightbox` both for a function and for a div id? Change name to the function please, maybe the problem could be here.

3) Always check if video_lightbox and divlightbox exist before accessing them.